# How does .get function with an ArrayList, does that Index become empty?

Tags: java, arraylist, imageview, vbox, hbox

I'm writing a program that has an `ImageView`'s`Arraylist`. I am using the `.get()` to take a dice `imageview` out from one `arraylist` and I add it to another `Arraylist` that is going to show all the dice that get chosen. I'm confused because does using the `.get()` remove it from the original `Arraylist`?

```
ArrayList<ImageView> rolledhand=new ArrayList<>(5);
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt(6);
        rolledhand.add(diceingame.get(randomNum));
    }

    VBox diceRolled1=new VBox(rolledhand.get(0));
    VBox diceRolled2=new VBox(rolledhand.get(0));
```

In my code above, the `diceingame` `ArrayList` already has 6 image view dice added to it. I randomly choose one and add it to my `rolledhand` array list 5 times. When I try to output the same index of `rolledhand`, only one shows up on my scene, not two of the same.

---

I'm not trying to remove it. I'm just asking because for some reason my program won't show both dice if they are from the same position in `diceingame`.

Comment: No. `get()` just `get`, not remove anything.

Comment: Did you get the answer for your question? Any feedback would be helpful for other readers.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList#get()` does not remove anything. It just `gets` the element:

> public E get(int index)
>
> Returns the element at the specified position in this list.

[ArrayList#get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get-int-)

If you want to `get` and `remove` the element at a position, use `ArrayList#remove()` instead:

> public E remove(int index)
>
> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).

[ArrayList#remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-)

Or if you want to pop out the element (get and remove the first/last element), use `Queue` or `Stack`.

### [Edit]

---

About your question that only one element appears on the view, according to the [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) document (which `ImageView` is inherited from):

> A node may occur at most once anywhere in the scene graph. Specifically, a node must appear no more than once in all of the following: as the root node of a Scene, the children ObservableList of a Parent, or as the clip of a Node.
>
> ...
>
> If a program adds a child node to a Parent (including Group, Region, etc) and that node is already a child of a different Parent or the root of a Scene, the node is automatically (and silently) removed from its former parent.

Comment: If you remove the element from the list, you should probably also reduce the value of the argument to `nextInt(6)`

Comment: im not trying to remove it. Im just wondering why the second time i try to output the same index from in rolled hand it does not work.

Comment: @PaulAnthonyMorillo Because _A node may occur at most once anywhere in the scene graph._, according to the docs. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: are there alternative ways to make copies? @Andreas

Comment: @PaulAnthonyMorillo you should instantiate another `ImageView` with the same image src. Afaik, there is no other formal way.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5224922/5221149) for how to get random values with no duplicates.